# Saving Object and using it acorss activites in android

Tags: android

How to save object in one Activity and accessing it across rest of the activites.
I have used intent but not working since some previous Activites get destroyed and i want it internal to my applciation?
regards

Comment: What kind of object you want to save ?

Comment: I did not try SharedPreferences i want to store object of type BluetoothDevice.

Comment: you can create one singleton class and store your object to it and use throught the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
final public class ObjectClass{

public static ObjectClass instance;
private Object object;

private ObjectClass() {

}


public static ObjectClass getInstance() {

    if (null == instance) {
        instance = new ObjectClass();
    }

    return instance;

}



public Object getObject() {
return object;
}

public void setObject(Object obj) {
this.object = obj;
}

}
```

In Activity

```
// to get object
ObjectClass.getInstance().getObject();

// to set object

ObjectClass.getInstance().setObject(your_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to save object of type(MyObject), you can make a global class for your application like:

```
public class GlobalApplication extends Application
{
MyObject myObject;

    public MyObject getMyObject() {
    return myObject;
    }

    public void setMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
    this.myObject = myObject;
    }
}
```

In your activity save object something like this:

```
GlobalApplication globalApplication = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
globalApplication.setMyObject(new MyObject());
```

To retrieve object , do this:

```
GlobalApplication globalApplication = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
globalApplication.getMyObject();
```

So basically you are creating your own Application class & extending it by default Application Class

Comment: Saving object in one Activity is ok but in other Activity how to retrieve it since making another object in second activity could not get the same object i saved in previous Activity.

Comment: I found solution by creating singleton class